# contraction mapping unique solution

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I am currently revising metric spaces and have come across a question slightly different to ones i am used to and would appreciate any hints as to how to attempt this question

[here is a photo of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnKu6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\mid \lambda\int_0^2y^2f(y)dy +\mid\lambda\mid f(x/4)\mid\leq \mid\lambda\mid\int_0^2y^2\|f\|dy +3\mid\lambda\mid\|f\|\leq \mid\lambda\mid\|f\|[(1/3)y^3]_0^2 +3\mid\lambda\mid\|f\|\leq (8/3)\mid\lambda\mid\|f\|+3\mid\lambda\mid\|f\|\leq (17/3)\mid\lambda\mid\|f\|$.

Thus if $(17/3)\mid\lambda\mid<1$ the function defined by $F(f(x))=\lambda\int_0^2y^2f(y)dy +\lambda f(x/4)$ is a contracting function and the Banach fixed point theorem implies that there exists a unique function $f$ such that $F(f(x))=f(x)$ since $\| \|$ is complete.